# Producer as non-reactive kafka and consumer as reactive kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, reactive-kafka

What happens if I use a non-reactive Kafka producer in service A and a reactive consumer in service B?

Answer (score 0):

The frameworks used don't matter for Kafka since at the internal library, it's all the same producer and consumer classes and TCP packets being transferred

Comment: not clear from above answer, Is it recommend to use reactive kafka consumer with non-reactive producer?

Comment: It doesn't matter, so there's no recommendation. If you have a more specific question about how the library handles backpressure and throughput, then that matters